# Jenkins with Mesos for Non container Tasks

Tags: jenkins-plugins, mesos

My usecase would be running jenkins jobs on windows slaves where I have mesos agents running. 
The jenkins-mesos plugin that is available spins up jenkins slave as containers. Is there any jenkins plugin out there which will connect jenkins master to mesos master & run the jobs on agents without any containers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [By default, the Jenkins slaves are run in the default Mesos container. To run the Jenkins slave inside a Docker container, there are two options.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin#docker-containers)

---

> [The MesosContainerizer currently does **not** provide any actual resource isolation (similar to running the Mesos agent on POSIX).](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/windows/#known-limitations)

---

`default Mesos container` is working on Windows so there shoul not be any problem to run Jenkins on Windows with Mesos. You need to install Java on agents.

Comment: But I do not need containers on agents. I want to run jobs on windows agents such as in any windows servers. The only thing I wanted to check on is how can i connect jenkins with mesos master ?

Comment: Default container in default configuration just runs a normal process

Comment: Do you mean when we use the jenkins-mesos plugin with default mesos container, its like any other normal  process on windows agents?

Comment: That's right [The MesosContainerizer currently does not provide any actual resource isolation (similar to running the Mesos agent on POSIX).](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/windows/#known-limitations)